# JSONP request returns results but also fires error_callback

Tags: javascript, google-closure-library

I'm using the Google Closure Library for a large scale web app. Basically I am sending a cross domain request to get some JSON data from a server. The data is returned properly and everything works just fine, but the function specified as an error_callback for the JSONP.send method still fires and I cannot understand why.

[The source JavaScript File](http://www.niuzly.com/ajax/niuzly.base.page.index.js)

This is the code that fires the JSONP request.

```
JSONPhandler.send({
    action: 'getAllPublishers', start: 0, length: 15},
    goog.bind(function(callback) {
        progressBar.setValue(100);
        goog.style.showElement(progressBarContainer, false);
        goog.dom.append(this.mainViewPublications,
                initItems.call(this, callback));
}, this), errorHandler.displayError('UNKNOWN'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the server response type for a JSONP request is not application/json, the error callback is never fired:)